# When is a scope variable updated when it depends on a service in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, angularjs-scope

Let us say that I have the following controller with the following service:

```
angular.module('ionicApp').controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, MyService){

    $scope.MyVariable = MyService.getMyVariable();

    $scope.updateMyVariable = function(valueFromHTML){
        MyService.setMyVariable(valueFromHTML);
        $scope.MyVariable = MyService.getMyVariable();
    };
})

.service("MyService", function(){
    this.MyVariable = {};

    this.getMyVariable = function(){
        return this.MyVariable;
    }

    this.setMyVariable = function(value){
        this.MyVariable = value;
        return true;
    }

});
```

Now let us take the following HTML:

```
<div class="instance-1" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div class="info-from-controller">
        <p>{{MyVariable}}</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="instance-2" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="updateMyVariable('newValue')">Click me</button>
</div>
```

And let us say that it is not possible to put the 2 html parts in the same div, it has to be a different instance of the controller.

If I press the button, thus changing the content of the variable in the service, will it also change the value of the variable in both scopes, since it's calling the service ?

I would naturally say "only in the scope being in the same instance as the button updating the variable". My impression is confirmed by [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rsr2grg/).

But then, how should I proceed to update the second scope as well? Is there a way to "trigger" the controller so it checks the content of the service again?

The ideal solution, in my case, would be to be able to **call the content of the service from the HTML**. However, I don't know how to do it, after having tried many things.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `updateMyVariable`, it updates `$scope.MyVariable` only in the 2nd instance. You're right, you should call the content of the service from the template.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rsr2grg/1/

Calling functions directly from the template can greatly reduce the performance of the application. It is worth doing this only when the called function does not perform complex actions. For example, when it only gets some variables/properties/etc. But in your case everything is ok.

Comment: I didn't know I could call the service directly from the template, thanks for the tip. Indeed, I don't perform complex operations so everything should be alright in my case. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> If I press the button, thus changing the content of the variable in the service, will it also change the value of the variable in both scopes, since it's calling the service ?

No

Service doesn't have scope and therefore digest cycle will not effect on your value.

Other controller has own scope and you need to broadcast event to call

```
$scope.MyVariable = MyService.getMyVariable();
```

or to trigger digest cycle

---

As a side note:

its not good practice to use controllers with the same name. Use components or directives to avoid unexpected behavior

Comment: @AlexanderFilimonov you have 2 instances of the same controller where `$scope` has own id. Even both have the same Service, 2nd controller doesn't know about change. Also updated answer

Comment: I misunderstood the previous version of your answer. I agree with you

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I take it gladly as I still lack experience with AngularJS. Alexander's solution resolved my problem but the information you gave me helped me understand the problem better. I think I will go through the structure of my application and try to solve these problems of controller getting called from different places. Thanks again!